# Method binding is not working in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to attached a controller scope method in a directive but when i click in directive button that linked method is not called. Please review code. There is side-nav directive in which i have attached method with select parameter. but when button is clicked method is not called.

index.html

```
 <div class="container" layout="row" flex ng-controller="userController as vm" ng-init="vm.loadUsers()">
        <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-whiteframe-1dp">
           <side-nav users="vm.users" select="vm.selectUser(user)"></side-nav>

        </md-sidenav>
        <md-content id="content" flex>
           <user-detail selected="vm.selected" share="vm.share()"></user-detail>           
        </md-content>
    </div>
```

userController.js

```
app.controller("userController", ['$scope', 'userService', '$mdBottomSheet', function ($scope, userService, $mdBottomSheet) {
    var self=this;
    self.users = [];
    this.name = "manish";

    self.loadUsers = function () {
        userService
            .loadAllUsers()
            .then(function (users) {
                self.users = users;
                self.selected = users[0];
                userService.selectedUser = self.selected;                
            });
    }

    self.selectUser = function (user) {
        self.selected = user;
        userService.selectedUser = self.selected;
    }

}]);
```

directives.js

```
app.directive("sideNav", function () {
    return {
        restrict :'AE',
        templateUrl: './views/sidenav.html',
        scope : {
            select : '&',
            users : '='
        }
    }
});
```

./views/sidenav.html

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="user in users">
        <md-button ng-click="select({user:user)">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="{{user.avatar}}" class="avatar"></md-icon>
            {{user.name}}
        </md-button>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Comment: `select({user:user)`: that is not valid code. A right curly brace is missing.

Comment: missed out in typo at last moment but even with this it was not working. Just moment ago i changed method name from selectUser to some other name now it is being called. I am not sure what is wrong with selectUser word. You can try with it by placing selectUser in both controller and directive

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this:

index.html

```
<side-nav users="vm.users" select="vm.selectUser"></side-nav>
```

./views/sidenav.html

```
<md-button ng-click="select()(user)">
```